# Net use works in batch file, fails in script

Tags: windows-7, scripting, batch-file

We are a small office with a Linux appliance server (SAMBA) and Win7HP on the desktops. We have one machine that acts as a "backup server" and backs up the server nightly.

Writing what was supposed to be a quick & dirty addition to the backup script that would loop like this:

```
a. net use * /d /y
b. net use u: \\ourserver\userNN /u:userNN password
c. run sync util to sync u: to this user's storage space on backup server
d. repeat
```

If I manually create the above in a batch file, everything works fine. (However, for many reasons the procedure must be automated and tied into our existing backup scripts.)

If a script creates the identical batch file and runs it, the first user is logged-in and syncronized, but all subsequent `net use` attempts fail.

Similarly, if the script attempts to map the drive through code, this message is received:

`Unrecognised network error #183`

The above error suggests that the network drive/path is unavailable -- but a net use command typed at the command line using identical parameters is successful.

The "backup server" is a Win7HP box with UAC disabled. When cmd prompt is launched, all windows are preceded by the word: `Administrator:` -- however, when the script launches a command window to net use the drive, the cmd titlebar lacks that prefix.

Any thoughts / ideas?

Comment: "procedure must be automated".  Have you ever looked into Scheduled Processes? [See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). OR `Control Panel->System and Security->Administrative Tools->Task Scheduler`

Comment: Sounds like permissions to me.  When the script creates and runs this batch file, it's running as a different user than when *you* run it, and likely you have more permissions on the network than it does.

Comment: If you are running using task scheduler you must ensure that the task runs under an account with network privileges, e.g. you. tasks that run under the default local system computer account will be locked down.

Answer (score 0):

In order for users to execute this code properly, they will need to have the proper credentials to do so. Also to automate this task, just use Task Scheduler and it should work fine.